# Too much string on the tuning peg?

Tags: guitar, strings, classical-guitar

I just finished changing the strings for my classical guitar. This is the first time so it wasn't absolutely smooth.

Now, tuning my E string (the highest) I noticed that it gets quite tense and all. I guess that it's normal however because of how I wound the strings, my E string on the tuning peg gets all stacked up on one side:

[image: Close look on the e string]

See that and whenever I need to tight the string up, it kinda makes a sound that makes me think it wouldn't be able to wind up anymore!

My question is what should I do? Do I let it stay like this and tighten the string up whenever it's needed? Or should I remove the string and wind it up all over again? In that case would it affect the quality of the string and the sound?

Comment: Also, you might be interested in this thread: [Beginner replacing guitar strings](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12616/beginner-replacing-guitar-strings/12618)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it over again, and have about half as many loops on the peg as you have now. See [this guide](https://www.taylorguitars.com/sites/default/files/Nylon_Restring.pdf) for some more hints.

Comment: It wouldnt change the quality right? And how do we do it with less loops? It still has the be tense enough. Do i cut off half of the strings?

Comment: Yes, cut off a few inches that are spare at the end, after you've pulled some of the string through the hole in the post.Or leave it flapping around...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the string is butting up against the headstock itself, so if you wind the string up more it'll be fouling on the wood which won't help with tone etc and in the end will make a rut in the wood where the string is fouling.

That's not "major damage" but it's undesirable, and the wood fouling on the string will affect the tone even if only a little bit.

I would unwind it so that you can move the string through the hole oin the peg, pull it tight and then start winding again to hopfully take up more slack.

The alternative would be to pull the string through the hole, and pull it towards the middle of the headstock and see if it'll 'want to' wind over the peg, over the hole and not as far up the peg at the other end

Comment: How will it affect the tone? The string isn't vibrating once it's over the nut.

Comment: I only know this through experience, not through thorough understanding, but it seems if the string (even outside the nut/bridge) is resting on something even remotely flexible, then as the string tenses and relaxes during vibration, some of the tension whcih wants to pull it straight is spent moving the wood about, albeit a very small abount. Admittedly my experience of this was with an electric guitar where maybe things are more sensitive to such stuff.

Comment: Actually, taking another look, maybe in this case it won't reeally affect the tone so much here as the point it's pushed against the wood is right near the peg anyway